# How do I turn on WiFi and WebCam on Medion AKOYA E7214 laptop?

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, shortcut-keys, 18.04

The <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> / <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> are the keyboard toggles for Wifi and WebCam respectively.  These don't seem to work in Bionic.  The BIOS is unhelpful offering either off or last state for each of these. The machine is dual boot but Windows 10 doesn't appear to use these key combinations either.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't obvious but Medion's support website has a downloadable Windows driver/program called "Launch Manager" (for Win7).  This is needed on Win 10 to use the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> & <kbd>F9</kbd> key combinations.  After installing Launch Manager and turning on WiFi and WebCam in Win10 with the BIOS set to "last state", Ubuntu can access WiFi and Camera on the laptop. I can now use Skype and WiFi.